# Tool to keep track of which dynamic power management technique is being used by my Linux machine

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, power-management

I have read that the OS on computers uses one of the Dynamic Power Management (DPS) or Dynamic Voltage Frequency Scaling (DVFS) techniques to reduce power consumption by a process.

I want to know if there is any software for Ubuntu 16.04 OS that can tell me which power management technique it uses to reduce the power consumption. My assumption is that it uses different power reduction techniques at different times. Can we keep track of this?